# Syntax highlighting on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want to edit template files of a common forum cms. However they store views like this:

```
[...]
function globalTemplate($html, $documentHeadItems, $css, $jsModules, $metaTags, array $header_items, $items=array(), $footer_items=array(), $stats=array()) {
$IPBHTML = "";
$IPBHTML .= <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
[...]
```

This disables highlighting. It's like editing committed html. Do you guys know how to enable highlighting with this example of code?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, indeed!

Select all HTML code between the `<<<EOF` and `EOF`. Wait. A lamp icon will appear, click on it with left mouse button and select `Inject language/reference`. Select then `HTML` from the list, and you got it.

Comment: If OP can edit that file .. then it's even easier -- just change `EOF` to another marker -- `HTML` and HTML language will be injected automatically (as per language injections rules)